# Golang Switch i.(type) returning different type than reflect.TypeOf()

Tags: go

I have this function and it's returning different type.

Here's the playground link https://play.golang.org/p/ErNt-rJTEbz

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

func main() {
    a := []uint8{24, 12}
    var b interface{} = a
    
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(b)) // []uint8
    switch b.(type) {
    case []byte:
        fmt.Println("is byte")
    }
}

// output: is byte
```

Comment: `byte` and `uint8` are *aliases*.

Comment: I wish Go code snippets worked here.  May some day.  For now you'll have to put your go code in ``` blocks instead, and we'll have to run it outside SO

Comment: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Numeric_types `byte        alias for uint8`

Answer (score 4):

`byte` is an alias of `uint8`. Try this, and it will show the error:

```
    switch b.(type) {
    case []byte:
        fmt.Println("is byte")
    case []uint8:
        fmt.Println("is uint8")
    }

duplicate case []uint8 in type switch
```